# JSONException: Unparsable JSON string in test

Tags: java, testing, jackson

I'm trying to run the next test:

```
@WebMvcTest(TuCasitaController.class)
class TuCasitaControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private TuCasitaService tuCasitaService;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetInfoHouse() throws Exception {
        /* Given */
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
        ObjectWriter ow = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String houseCorrect = ow.writeValueAsString(InfoTestGenerator.generatesCorrectTestInfo());
        String expected = ow.writeValueAsString(InfoTestGenerator.generateValidResponse());
        System.out.println(expected);
        /* When */
        mvc.perform(post("/info")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(houseCorrect))
        /* Then */
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json(expected));
    }
}
```

but it throws an org.json.JSONException "Unparsable JSON string" on the line `.andExpect(content().json(expected))`. This is the object I'm trying to parse:

```
public static Response generateValidResponse(){

    RoomArea room1 = RoomArea.builder().roomName("Recamara Principal").area(25).build();
    RoomArea room2 = RoomArea.builder().roomName("Recamara Daniel").area(28).build();
    RoomArea room3 = RoomArea.builder().roomName("Recamara Julieta").area(25).build();
    RoomArea room4 = RoomArea.builder().roomName("Sala").area(100).build();
    RoomArea room5 = RoomArea.builder().roomName("Comedor").area(16).build();
    RoomArea room6 = RoomArea.builder().roomName("Cocina").area(12).build();
    List<RoomArea> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
    rooms.add(room1);
    rooms.add(room2);
    rooms.add(room3);
    rooms.add(room4);
    rooms.add(room5);
    rooms.add(room6);

    return Response.builder()
            .nameHouse("Casa Familiar")
            .totalArea(206.0)
            .totalPrice(515000.0)
            .biggestRoom(RoomDTO.builder()
                    .roomName("Sala")
                    .roomWidth(10)
                    .roomLength(10)
                    .build())
            .roomAreas(rooms)
            .build();
}
```

And it looks like this when I print it after the objectWriter:

```json
{
  "nameHouse" : "Casa Familiar",
  "totalArea" : 206.0,
  "totalPrice" : 515000.0,
  "biggestRoom" : {
    "roomName" : "Sala",
    "roomWidth" : 10.0,
    "roomLength" : 10.0
  },
  "roomAreas" : [ {
    "roomName" : "Recamara Principal",
    "area" : 25.0
  }, {
    "roomName" : "Recamara Daniel",
    "area" : 28.0
  }, {
    "roomName" : "Recamara Julieta",
    "area" : 25.0
  }, {
    "roomName" : "Sala",
    "area" : 100.0
  }, {
    "roomName" : "Comedor",
    "area" : 16.0
  }, {
    "roomName" : "Cocina",
    "area" : 12.0
  } ]
}
```

Anyone knows why I'm having this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using:
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

Instead of: @WebMvcTest(TuCasitaController.class) solved it.

Answer (score 0):

JSON parsing might be affected by `withDefaultPrettyPrinter()`. Try it without it.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably happening because you are not Mocking your Service method properly. You MUST mock the service in order for it to work.

Example:

`Mockito.when(fooService.foo(fooString)).thenReturn(fooReturn);`